# To show from which table does the data come from with an union

Tags: sql, database, union

Im creating a Database from two sources , the sources are as follows

```
Create Table table_name1(Column_A VARCHAR(50), Column_B int, Column_C VARCHAR(50), Column_D VARCHAR(50));

Insert Into table_name1 Values
('A1',5,'C1','D1'),
('A1',23,'C2',null),
('A2',2,'C2','D1'),
('A12',23,'C2',null),
('A2',23,'C2',null), 
('A12',12,'D2','C1');

Create Table table_name2(Column_A VARCHAR(50), Column_B int, Column_C VARCHAR(50), Column_D VARCHAR(50));

Insert Into table_name2 Values
('A1',5,'C1','D1'),
('A1',23,'C2',null),
('A1',21,'C2',null),
('A2',2,'C2','D1'),
('A2',34,'C2','D1'),
('A21',23,'C2','D1'),
('A2',23,'C2','D2'), 
('A12',12,'D2','C1'),
('A12',23,'C2',null),;
```

Now i would like to union these two sources and generate ID's based on the business logic but at the same time i would like to know which data source is data coming from in a separate column 'table1' if it is from table1 and 'table2' if it is from table2 and if it is a common data then 'table1 & table2'

So far i wrote as follows

```
with t1 as(
select * from table_name1
union
select * from table_name2)

select dense_rank() over ( order by Column_B) as id_1,
dense_rank() over(order  by t1.Column_A,t1.Column_C,t1.Column_D) as id_2, t1.Column_A,t1.Column_B,t1.Column_C, t1.Column_D
from t1
```

Expected Output:
[image: output]

Comment: What DBMS are you currently using?

Comment: I believe you are using Oracle. If yes then please tag the question with that.

Answer (score 3):

Another solution (I am working in Mariadb and don't have the dense_rank function - you can add that):

EDITED to make the Source more exactly what the OP requested:

```
SELECT  Column_A,
            Column_B,
            Column_C,
            Column_D,
            CONCAT("Table ",GROUP_CONCAT(TNAME1,TNAME2 ORDER BY TNAME2 SEPARATOR  "&" )) AS Source
    FROM 
        (SELECT Column_A,
            Column_B,
            Column_C,
            Column_D,
            "1" AS TNAME1,
            "" AS TNAME2
            FROM table_name1
        UNION
        SELECT  Column_A,
            Column_B,
            Column_C,
            Column_D,
            "" AS TNAME1,
            "2" AS TNAME2
            FROM table_name2
        ) AS SQL1
    GROUP BY Column_A,Column_B,Column_C,Column_D;
```

[image: Result:]

Answer (score 2):

Would something like this work for you if @lemon's solution doesn't?

```
with cteConsolidate as (
select 'Table 1' as tabname, * from #table_name1
union
select 'Table 2' as tabname, * from #table_name2
)
select column_a, column_b, column_c, column_d, case when count(*) = 1 then min(tabname) else 'Both' end 
from cteConsolidate
group by column_a, column_b, column_c, column_d
```

Answer (score 1):

If `EXCEPT` and `INTERSECT` are operators available for your DBMS, like in PostgreSQL and MySQL, you can apply a union over the three separate sets:

- records appearing in table1 but not in table2
- records appearing in table2 but not in table1
- records appearing in both tables

```
SELECT *, 'tab1' AS orig FROM table1 EXCEPT SELECT * FROM table2
UNION ALL
SELECT *, 'tab2' AS orig FROM table2 EXCEPT SELECT * FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT *, 'both' AS orig FROM table1 INTERSECT SELECT * FROM table2
```